# Problem with “Employee with independent job income” schema design with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema

learning mongoDb. Looking for the right schema solution :
Have -employees, every -employee got own type of -job, and every -type of job got its own —income. How would the right schema look for this, so there would be possible to add new types of jobs with its own income data for employee and to do all necessary math operations with all income data in the future?

```
Const mongoose = require(‘mongoose’)
Const Schema = mongoose.Schema

Const employeeSchema = new schema({

   employeeName: {type: string},
   job: [
          {
            jobName:{type: string},
            jobIncome:{type: number}
            date: {type: Date, default : Date.now}
          }
        ]

})
```

Is that schema looks right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Const mongoose = require(‘mongoose’)
Const Schema = mongoose.Schema

Const employeeSchema = new schema({

   employeeName: {type: string},
   job: [
          {
            reference:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Job",
                required: true},
            joiningDate: {type: Date, default : Date.now},
            lastDate: {type: Date}
          }
        ]
})
```

Defination of job schema - you can have other fields as well

```
Const jobSchema = new schema({
    title:{ type:string},
    income:{type:number}
})
module.exports = Job = mongoose.model("Job", jobSchema);
```